# Terminology for rotated slice of a circle

Tags: geometry, terminology, circles

I know the term "torus" is generally used to describe a circle rotated about some axis that is coplanar with the circle.

Does the the term also apply if you rotate a small section of a circle instead?

Say, take a circle, and then intersect the circle with a line that intersects the circle in two points and doesn't pass through its center. This line will split the circle into a smaller and larger piece. Take the smaller piece and rotate it about the line used to cut the circle. Can that shape correctly be called a torus? If not, what is the correct term?

Comment: This is similar to a spindle torus.. except that it's only the "inside" part of what is usually termed a spindle torus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, the word "torus" implies that the surface is actually homeomorphic to the canonical "donut" shape.

The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus) mention the names "horn torus" and "spindle torus" for the shapes you get by rotating an *entire* circle around a tangent or a chord, respectively -- but these shapes would not normally be spoken about as unqualified "tori".

Your construction where a circular arc of less $180^\circ$ is rotated about its chord would produce the central spindle in a spindle torus. Topologically it's just a distorted sphere. You could call it a "spindle", or a "cigar shape", I suppose.

Comment: Thanks! I was considering "spindle" as well.